# iOS Build's fine in Xcode but Appcenter.ms fails

Tags: ios, xcode

Running, Archiving, & Building my app in Xcode gave me a `multiple commands produced` error.

So I found this [Github Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20492#issuecomment-422958184) where they said to add the following:

```
post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
                
                # The following is needed to ensure the "archive" step works in XCode.
                # It removes React & Yoga from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.
                # Without this, you'd see errors when you archive like:
                # "Multiple commands produce ... libReact.a"
                # "Multiple commands produce ... libyoga.a"
                
                targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)
                
                if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
                        target.remove_from_project
                end
                
        end
end
```

This allowed me to archive my app and run it successfully on a device via XCode. However, when trying to built it on [Appcenter.ms](https://Appcenter.ms) I get the following error and to be honest I have no idea what to do because it works fine on XCode so I have no way of testing against it.

> ld: 473 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do? Here is a [link to my logs](https://pastebin.com/raw/B4Pd7uDK) on all the duplicate errors that get added.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Build Settings and search for No Common Blocks and see what it is set to.  If it is set to YES, try setting it to NO.  Certain versions of xCode default to YES.